# how requests gets handled by dispacther servlet?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-webflow

Would like to know how many instances of dispatcher servlet is created in a real time environment.

When there are multiple requests coming to the application, and if spring creates singleton objects how does one object handles multiple requests?

What happens when there are so many people accessing the website and since dispatcherServlet object is only one and all requests are handled by same object, won't it create any performance issue?

Comment: One servlet to rule them all... Why wouldn't a single instance be capable of handling multiple request, you just have to make sure it is thread safe (i.e no shared state).

Comment: Thanks for answering but i m still confused wont there be any performance issue when there are lots of people accessing the website and for different threads that where created by cotainer all points to same dispacherServlet object?...please clarify this

Comment: No. Why do you think it is a problem, as long as there is no state a single object is perfectly capable of being used by multiple threads (each request is handled by a different thread). So no there won't be any issues (unless you are adding `synchronized` methods etc.).

Answer (score 1):

As M. Deinum says, one servlet to rule them all. I'll try to provide a very general description of the ServletDispatcher life cycle.

[image]

1. When the request leaves the browser it carries with it information from the user. This goes to the **DispatcherServlet** the front controller which is the **single servlet** that delegates requests to other components.
2. DispatcherServlet's job is to send the request to the right **controller**. Since a application can have many controllers **DispatcherServlets** get the help to decide which one to send it to by consulting the **handler mapping**
3. The **DispatcherServlet** sends the request to the destination **controller**,
4. The **controller** packs up the model-data and identifies the name of the **view** that is showing the output and sends this back to the dispatcherservlet.
5. **DispatcherServlet** consults with the **viewResolver** and looks up the view that is set to display the data.
6. The **view** is implemented (by a JSP for example) by using the model data to generate output. Which is sent back to the client.

This all happens very fast (ms) which means that thousands of requests can be handled in a very short time.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the wonderful explanation.I had the idea about the flow but i m confused if the dispactherServlet has only one object and it would have some memory location.Since lots of reuests coming to the application each threads will try to hit the same memory location.So does it gets handled by the application. Is it multiple thread accessible at a time?.Doesnt it create any performance issue?....Thanks in advance

Comment: Is it necessary to create multiple instance of dispatcher servlet for handling multiple request ? Just think about it this way, what is dispatcher servlet is a static class, with bunch of methods. multiple request calls these methods creates multiple stack memory entry. It is quiet okay that way. Now relax our assumption that dispatcher servlet is not a static object, instead it is a singletone, and everything as static applied, if no state is managed by dispatcher servlet. By state i mean, no member variable to manage any state of any request.